# KIF: Can KIF access the filesystem for an iOS app under test?

Tags: kif

Given an iOS 8 app that downloads some files for the purpose of caching them (i.e for offline use), is there a way that KIF can access the app's underlying file system to verify the files? I anticipate that someone will suggest that the app do this for us and display it in a help/about page for debug builds. I'm certainly open to that, but I want to know if that's the only real way to do it on a NON jailbroken iphone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally certain I understand the purpose of your question but let me try to answer anyway: KIF is for UI testing only. Files in a file system, that is backend not UI. What you want is to use unit testing, XCTest for example. KIF does run on top of Apple's XCTest framework but is only for Functional/UI testing. XCTest is very simple and if you know KIF you will be able to write XCTests too.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are testing against simulators.

Then yes it can. Basically, test and your app are in the same process, whatever you can do in app, you can do that in tests.